# js jquery session

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть 3 функции:

1)посылает запрос серверу и записывает ответ в сессию:

```
var updateHideWord = function(){
$.getJSON("/game/ajaxtest",
    function (data) {
        var word = data.word;
        alert(word);
        $.session.set("hideWord",data.word);
    });
}
```

2) отображает на форме содержимое сессии:

```
var showHideWord = function(){
    var element = document.querySelector('.word');
    var word = getHideWord();
    element.innerHTML = 'Слово:' + word;
}
```

3) Геттер переменной в сессии

```
var getHideWord = function(){
    return $.session.get("hideWord");
}
```

Я вызываю это в функции по нажатию кнопки на форме в такой последовательности:

```
updateHideWord();
showHideWord();
```

но валидное значение из getHideWord() в showHideWord() я получить после первого нажатия не могу, всёвремя undefined. Я плохо знаком с js, поэтому буду благодарен за пояснение такого поведения и решения данной проблемы - т.е. функцию showHideWord() на вызвать только после того, когда переменная "hideWord" перестанет быть undefined. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Может потому, что ответ от сервера ещё не пришел и `$.session.set("hideWord",data.word);` не выполнилось. Прочитайте про ассинхронные запросы. `showHideWord();` засунте после `$.session.set("hideWord",data.word);`

Comment: ответ приходит, в alert это четко видно

Comment: Еще раз ответ приходит !!ассинхронно!! вы меня понимаете? Повторюсь: `showHideWord();` засунте после `$.session.set("hideWord",data.word);`

Comment: спасибо, разобрался